# Trying to create c aggregate in postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql 12 on linux box. Latter when I am trying to execute my make getting below error.

```
make: pg_config: Command not found
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
-bash-4.2$

-bash-4.2$ cat Makefile
MODULES = addme
EXTENSION = addme
DATA = addme--0.0.1.sql
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
-bash-4.2$
```

Can someone help me how to install pg_config library?

Comment: You must install the C headers. If you installed from packages, install the -devel or -dev package.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe is Already installed. Pasted output same. Please let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: Please don't add additional information as "answer", edit the question. What you show is a package from PostgreSQL 9.2. Uninstall all PostgreSQL packages from other versions and install the correct one. Then put `pg_config` in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PostgreSQL package with the C headers.  For a RedHat-based system, that would be `postgresql12-devel`.